# TinkerPop: Generic Query to combine and filter multiple traversals

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3, gremlin-server

Sample data: [TinkerPop Modern Graph](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/images/tinkerpop-modern.png)

Conditions:

1. Is `vadas` connected to `lop` within `2 hops`
2. Is `vadas` connected to `peter` within `3 hops`
3. Is `vadas` connected to `does-not-exists` in `1 hops` *(a search that wont give any results)*

Dummy searches with expected results

1. Conditions `1` AND `2`
   => [vadas-marko-lop, vadas-marko-lop-peter]
2. Conditions `1` OR `3` 
   => [vadas-marko-lop]

---

What I was able to get

1. Conditions `1` AND `2`

```
gremlin> g.V().has("person", "name", "vadas").as("from")
.select("from").as("to1").repeat(both().as("to1")).times(2).emit().has("software", "name", "lop")
.select("from").as("to2").repeat(both().as("to2")).times(3).emit().has("person", "name", "peter")
.project("a", "b")
.by(select(all, "to1").unfold().values("name").fold())
.by(select(all, "to2").unfold().values("name").fold())
==>[a:[vadas,marko,lop],b:[vadas,marko,lop,peter]]
```

2. Conditions `1` OR `2`

```
gremlin> g.V().has("person", "name", "vadas").as("nodes")
.union(repeat(both().as("nodes")).times(2).emit().has("software", "name", "lop"),
out().has("x", "y", "does-not-exist").as("nodes"))
.project("a")
.by(select(all, "nodes").unfold().values("name").fold())
==>[a:[vadas,marko,lop]]
```

**So how to achieve this I have two different query formats, is there a way to writer a query format that can do both?**

And this did not work, anything wrong here? Does not return the nodes that have been traversed

```
g.V().has("person", "name", "vadas").as("nodes")
.or(
repeat(both().as("nodes")).times(2).emit().has("software", "name", "lop"), 
repeat(both().as("nodes")).times(3).emit().has("person", "name", "peter")
)
.project("a").by(select(all, "nodes").unfold().values("name").fold())
==>[a:[vadas]]
// Expect paths to be printed here vadas..lop, vadas...peter
```

Comment: i can't say i fully follow the problem. what do you mean by "generic"? that seemed to be the big emphasis for your question but it's not clear what that means to me.

Comment: I can mostly achieve `and`  and `or` logics with 2 different methods, is there a better way to combine these two?

Comment: i'm still not following. Gremlin has `and()`/`or()` steps for conditional logic, but i don't know what you mean by a "better way to combine these two"? are you saying that you want another way to write the traversals you have above that doesn't use those two steps somehow?

Comment: I'll update the post to try explain better

Comment: I have edited the post, better now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I understand what you're after, but if you just need something like a query template, then maybe this will help:

```
gremlin> conditions = [
......1>   [filter: {has("software", "name", "lop")},  distance: 2],
......2>   [filter: {has("person", "name", "peter")},  distance: 3],
......3>   [filter: {has("x", "y", "does-not-exist")}, distance: 1]]
==>[filter:groovysh_evaluate$_run_closure1@378bd86d,distance:2]
==>[filter:groovysh_evaluate$_run_closure2@2189e7a7,distance:3]
==>[filter:groovysh_evaluate$_run_closure3@69b2f8e5,distance:1]

gremlin> g = TinkerFactory.createModern().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> g.V().has("person", "name", "vadas").
......1>   union(repeat(both().simplePath()).
......2>           times(conditions[0].distance).
......3>           emit().
......4>         filter(conditions[0].filter()).store("x"),
......5>         repeat(both().simplePath()).
......6>           times(conditions[1].distance).
......7>           emit().
......8>         filter(conditions[1].filter()).store("x")).
......9>   barrier().
.....10>   filter(select("x").
.....11>          and(unfold().filter(conditions[0].filter()),
.....12>              unfold().filter(conditions[1].filter()))).
.....13>   path().
.....14>     by("name")
==>[vadas,marko,lop]
==>[vadas,marko,lop,peter]

gremlin> g.V().has("person", "name", "vadas").
......1>   union(repeat(both().simplePath()).
......2>           times(conditions[0].distance).
......3>           emit().
......4>         filter(conditions[0].filter()).store("x"),
......5>         repeat(both().simplePath()).
......6>           times(conditions[2].distance).
......7>           emit().
......8>         filter(conditions[2].filter()).store("x")).
......9>   barrier().
.....10>   filter(select("x").
.....11>          or(unfold().filter(conditions[0].filter()),
.....12>             unfold().filter(conditions[2].filter()))).
.....13>   path().
.....14>     by("name")
==>[vadas,marko,lop]
```

And a little more abstraction should make it clearer that the two queries only differ in 1 step (`and` vs `or`):

```groovy
apply = { condition ->
  repeat(both().simplePath()).
    times(condition.distance).
    emit().
  filter(condition.filter()).store("x")
}

verify = { condition ->
  unfold().filter(condition.filter())
}

// condition 1 AND 2   
g.V().has("person", "name", "vadas").
  union(apply(conditions[0]),
        apply(conditions[1])).
  barrier().
  filter(select("x").
         and(verify(conditions[0]),
             verify(conditions[1]))).
  path().
    by("name")

// condition 1 OR 3   
g.V().has("person", "name", "vadas").
  union(apply(conditions[0]),
        apply(conditions[2])).
  barrier().
  filter(select("x").
         or(verify(conditions[0]),
            verify(conditions[2]))).
  path().
    by("name")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, so `filter` has to be done twice, and it seems `or(...as("x"), ...as("y"))` will not store value into `x` and `y`. Am I right?

Comment: Only for current path, which is not helpful in your use-cases as your filter conditions depend on the final result.